# Convert this double match to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a listbox where a user can select one or more bus numbers from the buses they have booked (for upgrading).  I also have a list of all the buses that a person has booked BusFactory.lstBuses

This works fine, but what I want is a way to do it in linq.  The breakdown is it gets all the numbers that a user selects and matches it up with the buses that the user has booked, and returns a list of buses.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Bus> lstBuses = getSelectedBuses();
    }

    private List<Bus> getSelectedBuses()
    {
        List<Bus> lstBus = new List<Bus>();
        foreach (string s in lstBuses.SelectedItems)
        {
            foreach (Bus bus in BusFactory.lstBuses)
            {
                if (s == bus.ElementNumber.ToString())
                    lstBus.Add(bus);
            }
        }
        return lstBus;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lstBuses.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().Intersect(
    BusFactory.lstBuses.Select(b => b.ElementNumber.ToString())
)
```

This has the added benefit of being O(n) rather than O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. how do I add this to a new lstOfSelectedBuses?